# How to find process template applied to a project using tfs Api

Tags: tfs

i have seen may links on this but none of them works fine.In all cases either templateid comes -1 or processtemplate comes null.

```
  private ProjectProperty[] GetProcessTemplateDetailsForTheSelectedProject(string prjname)
    {
        var vcs = _tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        var ics = _tfs.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
        ProjectProperty[] ProjectProperties = null;

        var p = vcs.GetTeamProject(prjname);
        string ProjectName = string.Empty;
        string ProjectState = String.Empty;
        int templateId = 0;
        ProjectProperties = null;

        ics.GetProjectProperties(p.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri, out ProjectName, out ProjectState, out templateId, out ProjectProperties);
        IProcessTemplates processTemplates = (IProcessTemplates)_tfs.GetService(typeof(IProcessTemplates));

        XmlNode node = processTemplates.GetTemplateNames();


        return ProjectProperties;
    }
```

Please help in this regard.I want to find out the process template applied to a project programitcally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the Process Template name, if the process template was given a name before it was uploaded to TFS.

[image]

As you can see in the image, there is a property here "Process Template" which has a value i.e. name of the template. If you look for a property that does not exist, the api will return you -1, this is what you are running in to with the code above.

The code in the blog link here will help you get the process template name, again, only if, you gave the process template a name before uploading it. http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/11/15/tfs-api-process-template-currently-applied-to-the-team-project.aspx

Please note, all process templates in TFS 2012 have been named by default. This wasn't the case for TFS 2010.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: :When I am creating a new project in TFS 2010 it will ask for project template.there are 2 template coming by default.MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0 and MSF for CMMI Process Improvement v5.0.These are the name of the templates i guess.Please correct me if i am wrong.But while running the code it is coming null.